# lots of unwanted spacing,or whatever it is as soon as i added css script

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Satyam</title>
<style>
ul,li{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#0CE840,#EFFFE5);
display:inline-block;}
*{margin=0px;padding=0px;border:3px solid #000;background-attachment:fixed;
background-image: url("http://cdn.sploder.com/images/hp3/hp_multiplayer_sploderheads2.gif");
background-size:cover;}

#main{font-size:100px;box-sizing:border-
box;position:relative;bottom:90px;background-image:-webkit-linear-
gradient(#FFE259,#EFFFE5)}</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center" id="main">Gamerz!</h2>
<ul><h4>
<li>Home
<li>Courses
<li>Support
<li>Contact us</h4>
</ul>
</html>
```

Comment: unwanted spacing where? what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Could you add more details on what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I am getting a lots of extra space which i dont want,to fiqure this out i have to positon the box element but how long will i do this for all elements..

Comment: as soon as i added the CSS script lots of space added along,before adding it was normal

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Satyam</title>
  <style></style>
 </head>
<body>
<h2 id="main">Gamerz!</h2>
<ul><h4>
<li>Home
<li>Courses
<li>Support
<li>Contact us</h4>
</ul>
</html>

Comment: You might want to post error free CSS first and `H4` are not allowed inside `ul` either. Helping < > debugging.

Comment: can you please edit the code for me? @RenevanderLende

Comment: Sure I can, actually working on that right now. But I can guarantee you, Satyam, when you remain this sloppy you will never cross that river on your own...

Comment: actually i learned html and css today for the first time i was just trying a code for the first time

Comment: You are forgiven, but with all the CSS possibilities you really have to get very meticuleous and learn what the general structure of a CSS and HTML file is. Seriously! (about to finish my version...)

Comment: I'll make sure about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my comments before in the back of my mind, I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```css
/* Use the body for a nice background */
body {
  background-image: url("http://cdn.sploder.com/images/hp3/hp_multiplayer_sploderheads2.gif");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover
}

h2 { margin: 0 }

/* Is a container, only holding <li>'s */
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

/* Fontsize of H4 is actually 1rem/16px which generally is the default browser fontsize */
li {
  background: linear-gradient(#0CE840, #EFFFE5);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold /* is actually what you wanted from the <H4> */
}

/* We really didn't want add an image to ALL elements (which * actually means) */
* {
  border: 3px solid #000
}

#main {
  font-size: 100px;
  box-sizing: border- box;
  /* bottom: 90px; HUH? */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFE259, #EFFFE5)
}
/* linear- gradient (notice space) does nothing */
```

```html
<h2 align="center" id="main">Gamerz!</h2>
<ul>
  <!-- NO! H4 inside ul -->
  <li>Home
    <li>Courses
      <li>Support
        <li>Contact us
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rene but there is still so much space btween gamez! and the list below and also above gamerz1

Comment: Took a rounded 15minutes. That'll be $35,-- (ka'ching)

Comment: but that didn't affect my code a bit.Just the list items became bold else everything's the same

Comment: Got it, add `h2 { margin: 0 }` to the CSS to remove margin HTML adds to an `H2` element (or just rerun the snippet)

Comment: and the space b/w the list and Gamez!

Comment: And remove the **'r'** in Game**r**z! too, I guess?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Never mind the effect of H4 inside UL. It is not allowed and when we start accepting stuff like that already (after one day) how much need we accept by the time you are a crack at this? Because we can does not mean we should...

Comment: You are most welcome, time to properly close your question by marking it answered!